# Create a replace function in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, replace

Please Help me in creating a replace function.
Problem:
        Their is a alphanumeric value of any length (string) and I want to replace its all characters with 'X' except right four characters

Like :
      Value : 4111111111111111
Result Should be: XXXXXXXXXXXX1111

I have created a function but got stuck:

```
public function myfunction(str as string)
  str.Replace(str.Substring(0, str.Length - 5), 'X') 'but here I want no of x to be equals to count of length of str - 4
end function
```

What's a better function to perform such an operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this on for size.

```
Public Shared Function ObfuscateCardNumber(ByVal cardNumber As String) As String
    If cardNumber.Length <= 4 Then
        Return cardNumber
    Else
        Return cardNumber _
            .Substring(cardNumber.Length - 4, 4) _
            .PadLeft(cardNumber.Length, "X"c)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I fixed the character literal syntax on line 7, I do apologize for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim sNumber As String = "4111111111111111"
Dim sResult As String = StrDup(sNumber.Length - 4, "X"c) + Strings.Right(sNumber, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

something like

> string result for(int i = 0;i > str.length -4;i++) 
>   { 
>   result = result +x
>    } 
>   result = result + str.substrin(get
>   last 4)